# pyautogui.click() not working when converted to exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyautogui

I wrote this code to open Youtube and play a playlist using python 3.6 and `pyautogui`.

```
import os
import pyautogui as pygui
import time

path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
os.startfile(path)
time.sleep(2)

pygui.typewrite('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=rjkd2fadf') 
time.sleep(0.1)

pygui.press('enter')
time.sleep(3.5)

play=pygui.center(pygui.locateOnScreen('play.png'))
play=list(play)
pygui.click(play[0], play[1]-60, duration=0.7)                  
time.sleep(2)

loop=pygui.center(pygui.locateOnScreen('loop.png'))
pygui.click(loop, duration=0.5)

mini=pygui.center(pygui.locateOnScreen('minimze.png'))

pygui.click(mini, duration=0.2)
time.sleep(2)

chrome=pygui.center(pygui.locateOnScreen('chrome.png'))
pygui.rightClick(chrome, duration=0.1)
time.sleep(0.7)
new_tab=pygui.center(pygui.locateOnScreen('new_tab2.png'))
pygui.click(new_tab, duration=0.1)
```

I want this whole thing to be .exe, so I try the following:

```
pyinstaller -w -F main.py
```

After the url is entered and Enter is hit, the mouse doesn't move and I get the following error:

> Failed to execute script main

Comment: you can run `"chrome.exe url"` so you don't have to type url. There is even standard module `webbrowser` and `webbrowser.open(url)` will open url with default web browser. But to have better control you can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead of `webbrowser` and `pyautogui`

Comment: Do you have the error when removing `-w` flag? If yes put the error in the question.